# sqoop export with procedure option is failing

Tags: hadoop2, sqoop

I am trying to export the data from emr to postgre using sqoop. when I run below command, it is throwing the following exception

`sqoop export --connect jdbc:postgresql://test.xxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/RulesPOC --username user --password password   --call merge_AccountRepo  -m 1 --input-fields-terminated-by '|' --export-dir s3://<bucket_name>/output/ --driver org.postgresql.Driver  --columns "num,max"`

Error:

> 16/07/14 21:25:07 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
>   16/07/14 21:25:07 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Encountered IOException running export job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
>   [

Can someone please suggest what is wrong?

Comment: share complete error logs

Comment: also share the sample data to be exported. I think `--columns` is not a valid argument for `export` - can you try running with out `--columns` ?
https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax_3

Comment: I tried without columns option it did not work... the data is simple like number, max_amount i.e 123456, 10.00...

Comment: resolved the issue, source data columns and procedure input count should match... So i created a temp hive table to match the procedure input count, then I was able to export the data..